# How to make an illusion where the contents of a 3D shape change based on which face you look through?

Tags: unity, c#, rendering

I remember coming across a Unity 3D tutorial where there was a technique where the contents of a 3D shape change based on which face you are looking at, similar to this screenshot from Antichamber:

[image]

What is this techique called? And how do I implement it into a Unity 3D project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/12/09/3873/) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, this, and it did help in part, though it is a half-finished tutorial. The people in the comments have been asking him to finish the tutorial for years :) The non-euclidean tutorial part of the internet is pretty desolate, and really needs some attention. It's a great technique, just very hard for a beginner to understand and code.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to portal rendering. Typically this kind of effect is implemented with the [stencil buffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html).

You render each "viewport" on the shape's surface with a material that sets the stencil buffer to a specific value, but doesn't write to the z-buffer. Each face uses its own distinct value.

Then you render the contents of each view, using a material that checks whether the stencil buffer contains that specific key value. If it does, the object draws its pixels there. If it doesn't, those pixels are skipped.